# How to use the wrapper class in HTTP getmethod

Tags: class, wrapper-class

below is my code Created a wrapper class like below

```
public class ResponseWrapper{
    public list<Account> lstaccounts;
    public boolean isError ;
    public string errorCode;
    public integer statusCode;
       public ResponseWrapper(){
         lstaccounts = new list<Account>();
         isError= false;
    }
}


 @getMethod

@RestResource(urlMapping='/accounts/*')
 global with sharing class AccountRestService {
 @HttpGet
 global static ResponseWrapper getAccounts() {
     ResponseWrapper resWrap = new ResponseWrapper();
     List<Account> accounts;
     try {
         accounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
         res.lstaccounts = accounts;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
         resWrap.isError = true;
         res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage()) = resWrap.errorCode;
         res.statusCode = 500 = resWrap.statusCode;
     }
     return resWrap;
   }
 }
```

but iam getting the below Error: 
 Compile Error: global methods do not support return type of ResponseWrapper at line 4 column 31

Please check and suggest on this whats  the exact mistake i did.

Thanks & Regards. 
 Vamsi Krishna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a global method, your return type must also be global. Change your access modifier on the `ResponseWrapper` class from public to global.